# Xamarin Forms UI Test

Tags: user-interface, testing, xamarin.forms

When doing UI Tests in Xamarin does the test also perform the logic behind a control when interacting with it (e.g. pressing the login button and performing login authentication) or its only plain UI interaction (logic behind a control is not performed)?

Answer (score 3):

It tests the actual app, so pressing a button will fire the appropriate handlers, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

UI tests are more like UI commands that you send to your application. You check the UI state before an interaction and after an interaction (like the click of a button). Read more about it here https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/05/08/enterprise-ready-testing-in-xamarin/. It has a sample app as well